# Creating a map with sales data in SSRS, how do I connect my sales numbers to counties via county names?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My dataset looks something like this:

```
County Product Sales
CountyA ProductA 200
CountyA ProductB 150
CountyB ProductA 100
CountyB ProductB 300
CountyC Product A 50
etc...
```

I am using SSRS within Visual Studio. I am creating the map using the "Report Items" section of the toolbox.

I have the map with my state's counties, I associated the COUNTYNAME field with the County column in my data, but that's as far as I can get. I cannot seem to get the sales numbers to show on the map at all.

I can get the county names to show up on the map as labels, but that's not particularly helpful. If I choose [SUM(Sales)] nothing appears on the report.

Ultimately, I want a map of Product A sales vs Product B sales by county.

Is my dataset insufficient? And if so, what additional data do I need to add? Are there any steps I am missing to get the county associated with the sales column?

Comment: You need to decide where your problem lies. You have tagged integration services, reporting services and SQL. WHich environment are you working in? How are you associating? What components are you using? Much more information is needed before anyone can help you

Comment: I'm using SSIS within Visual Studio to create the map. My assumption is that the problem lies there, but like I said I don't know if my dataset is sufficient or if it's something else. If I knew for certain what the problem was I wouldn't need to ask for help.

Comment: But we can't help you if you don't describe what you are ding properly. You can't create maps with SSIS, it's an integration engine. Are you sure you aren't using SSRS? If so, are you creating a geographic map using shapedata ? You need to fully describe what you are doing.

Comment: You are correct, I meant SSRS. I will update my question.